# UIViewController as statemachine?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to have a general controller that acts as an abstract statemachine (not have any views/bars etc. of its own). Is the UINavigationController meant for this too?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to use `UIViewController` for this.  `UIViewController` inherently has a `UIView` that it controls--you'd be ignoring most of what `UIViewController` does.  A custom controller object would probably be more appropriate, unless you need specific non-view functionality in `UIViewController` (and I don't know why you would).

**EDIT:** Again, I'm not sure why `UINavigationController` would be a better fit. `UINavigationController` exists pretty much for the sole purpose of pushing and popping view controllers (along with displaying the navigation bar and whatnot).  Unless there's some specific functionality you want that comes with `UINavigationController`, I would just subclass `NSObject`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give you the best practise speach here.
You can do it, and if it suits your needs and you can do it I say why not. If you feel its a bad idea you should look for other solutions. Or at least try it if you believe it can work.

Tbh I once wrote a C# application that had a Panel object as a statemachine by pointing it to other panels and maintain state specific code in my classes that inherited from the panel class.